# Flutter Centering text in AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, coding-style, centering, appbar

i just want to Center this entire Text (of course it should be still in AppBar). Thx

[image: i want to centre entire text]

```
        appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 80.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            title: Row(children: [
              Text("Text",
                  style: GoogleFonts.josefinSans(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0))),
              Text(
                "The Game",
                style: GoogleFonts.overpass(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
              )
            ])),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.center` in `Row` widget

**Sample Code:**

```
AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 80.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            title: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              Text("Text",
                  style: GoogleFonts.josefinSans(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0))),
              Text(
                "The Game",
                style: GoogleFonts.overpass(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
              )
            ]))
```

Comment: you are god <3333

Answer (score 1):

Use **centerTitle : true**

```
appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            toolbarHeight: 80.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            title: Row(children: [
              Text("Text",
                  style: GoogleFonts.josefinSans(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0))),
              Text(
                "The Game",
                style: GoogleFonts.overpass(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
              )
            ])),
```

Comment: Ye, i tried this, it's working only if i am inserting "Column" instead of "Row". I dont know why

Comment: This solution works when we use `Text` widget in return for `title` value.

Comment: @Malak late reply, you need to set center child of Row too. 
`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`